# Limit before order by rand?

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way to limit before order by rand in this query?

```
$query = "SELECT username, user_img, user_cover_img FROM users WHERE username IN ('{$username_array}') ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 8";
```

It seems order by rand doesn't always include the usernames I need in the 8 that it returns.

Comment: Actually `ORDER BY` runs before `LIMIT`

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid by bad got my question switched around

Comment: Do you want to apply `LIMIT` first and then `ORDER BY`?

Comment: @zarruq yes that's correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use inner-query to apply `limit` and then `order by` in outer query as below.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT username
        ,user_img
        ,user_cover_img
    FROM users
    WHERE username IN ('{$username_array}') LIMIT 8
    ) t
ORDER BY RAND();
```

You query will look like

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT username,user_img,user_cover_img FROM users WHERE username IN ('{$username_array}') LIMIT 8) t ORDER BY RAND()";
```